# Old show that's a mix of Cardcaptor Sakura and Chaotic: kids can summon creatures they previously helped

Tags: story-identification, anime

It’s a show where these two kids would launch their ship through a portal bringing them to some different dimension with different types of creatures they would help, which would give them the ability to summon said creature for help in later episodes.

It was sort of similar to the concept of the show *Chaotic* with them getting whatever creature to agree to fight with them but was more of an anime than a cartoon.

Answer (score 3):

*The Mon Colle Knights* (2000).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mon_Colle_Knights):

> The series features Mondo Ooya and his girlfriend Rokuna Hiiragi, whose father Professor Ichiroubei Hiiragi invented a way to travel to Mon World (Roku Mon Sekai: the Six Gate World), where all sorts of magical creatures live. Together, they try to find six monster items which, when combined, could connect the Six Gate World with planet Earth for the better of both worlds.

The article also mentions that the two main characters can chant spells to merge with or control the monsters.